# Trying to create sprites with no overlap

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm trying to create this game that upon startup adds 50 sprites to the screen. I have the following in this sprite's `__init__` function:

```
if self.overlapping_sprites:
    for sprite in self.overlapping_sprites:
        self.game.make_obstacles(1, 1400, self.game.speed)
        self.die()
```

This pretty much detects if there are any overlapping sprites, and for each of those sprites, it creates a new sprite and deletes the offending sprite. Implementing this code did wonders, but it still isn't perfect. There are definitely still some overlapping sprites on load. Oh, I should mention I am creating these sprites randomly, based upon a given length.

For reference, this is what the `make_obstacles()` function is:

```
def make_obstacles(self, num, length, dx):
    for i in range(num):
        x = random.randrange(700, length)
        y = random.randrange(10, games.screen.height - 10)
        size = random.choice([Obstacle.obstacle_1,Obstacle.obstacle_3])
        new_obstacle = Obstacle(game = self, x = x, y = y, size = size, dx = dx)
        games.screen.add(new_obstacle)
```

Is there another way that I should try to accomplish my goal here? I'd also like to figure out why this is happening on a conceptual level to further my understanding, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Obvious solution?

I'm no expert with pygame; but I think I've figured out what the problem is here. I may be completely off though, because I'm not sure how the rest of the code looks.

You are making obstacles in your first block of code, and then not checking if those obstacles' sprites collide with other sprites! You're only checking whether they collide in the first code block; and this code block doesn't run on the obstacles created the second time.

To test if I'm correct, try removing the **self.game.make_obstacles** call in the first code block, so that colliding sprites are just deleted rather than recreated. Now, check if there are any sprite collisions.

Now that we've established there are none, set about rewriting your code. The way you've structured this, to me, seems a bit contrived - I used to write code like this for GameMaker. The apparent better way to write this code I feel would be to rewrite your **make_obstacles** method so that it checks for collisions before placing an obstacle. Have a while loop say something like

```
def make_obstacles(self, num, length, dx):
    for i in range(num):
        while True:
            x = random.randrange(700, length)
            y = random.randrange(10, games.screen.height - 10)
            size = random.choice([Obstacle.obstacle_1,Obstacle.obstacle_3])
            if is_empty(x, y, size):
                break
        new_obstacle = Obstacle(game = self, x = x, y = y, size = size, dx = dx)
        games.screen.add(new_obstacle)
```

**is_empty** is basically a boolean expression that evaluates to true when *x*, *y* is empty for obstacle *size* (i.e, no collision would result from placing an object there) and evaluates to false when *x*, *y* would collide with an already existing obstacle. Replace **is_empty** with a boolean expression that does what it's supposed to do.

Note here that this could result in a loop that never stops running! If the game screen is full of obstacles, the interpreter would continue evaluating  the contents of the *while True:* loop until the [expected end of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe). This means you need to either make sure you never have too many obstacles on the screen, or you need to try only a certain number of times before giving up. (in case of the latter choice, replace *while True:* with *for x in range(10000):* or some other appropriate number)

I hope that's solved the problem; comment below if you need any more help!

Comment: Ohhh I can see how my logic failed. It looks like is_empty sounds like exactly what I need.

But.. it seems as though I cannot get it to work, and it is near impossible to find a doc about it after searching. Would this happen to be a function that was introduced in a version later than 1.7?

Comment: Ok, I guess I realize now that it's a function I'll need to write. Hopefully I can figure this one out. we shall see! Thanks!